# Power BI Filter on the report level

Tags: powerbi

I have a big report that has 30+ pages

I have created a new page for filters

I added the Month filter in the filter page, this report is going to be filtered based on that month filter.

When I select a month, the filter works only for its page, does not apply filter for the whole report

How can I make filter apply for the whole report

PS : I have added the month to the report level filters, but this is not what I want.

This report is need filter control

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same slicer across multiple pages, then I'd recommend syncing them as explained in [slicer documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers#sync-and-use-slicers-on-other-pages).

Image from that page:
[image: Sync slicers]